# Choose which array to loop over

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am creating a javascript function to build the html for a calendar (in a `<table>`) for the current month. One of the parameters of the function is whether to write out the days of the week or use their initials. The full names and initials are both contained in arrays. The function will loop over one of the arrays to build the table cells that contain the days of the week. What is the best way to pick which array to loop over? Or should I be constructing this code in an entirely different way?

Code to illustrate my question:

```
buildCalendar(useFullNames){
    var fullNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday'], // etc.
        initials = ['S', 'M'],
        calString = '<tr>';

    if(useFullNames) {
        // use fullNames array in the loop 
    }     
    else {   
        // use initials array in loop
    }

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        // Need to loop over the array picked above
        calString += '<td>' + relevantArray[i] + '</td>';
    }

    calString += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: You can save the array you want in a variable, but how about just making a 2D array to begin with? The first index could be 0 or 1 based on useFullNames.

Comment: But it's easier to do the conditional once rather than each time through the loop.

Comment: @dmr Whatever solution you end up using, you may want to loop for `i<relevantArray.length` instead of `i<7` in case you ever want to change the range in the week. This way, you don't have to update code in multiple places, and it's "safer". Not too important, especially since I'm sure it'll always be 7, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var relevantArray = useFullNames ? fullNames : initials;
```

Comment: Is that perhaps what she said? :p

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this (pseudocode):

```
buildCalendar(dayOfWeekFormat){ //dayOfWeekFormat: "fullNames or "initials"
    var dayOfWeekFormat = { 
       fullNames: ['Sunday', ..., 'Saturday'],
       initials: ['S', ..., 'Sat']
    }
    var calString = '<tr>';

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        // Need to loop over the array picked above
        calString += '<td>' + daysOfWeek[dayOfWeekFormat][i] + '</td>';
    }

    calString += '</tr>';
}
```

`relevantArray` is an awful variable name. It doesn't tell you anything about what's in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like you have it set up, set the `relevantArray` variable

```
buildCalendar(useFullNames){
    var fullNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday'], // etc.
        initials = ['S', 'M'],
        calString = '<tr>',
        relevantArray;

    if(useFullNames) {
        // use fullNames array in the loop 
        relevantArray = fullNames;
    }     
    else {   
        // use initials array in loop
        relevantArray = initials;
    }

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        // Need to loop over the array picked above
        calString += '<td>' + relevantArray[i] + '</td>';
    }

    calString += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: boo! use the inline if defined above by @xdazz!

Comment: Yeah, because it's really that big of a deal. I was trying to use the same code/logic as the OP so they could understand better...